# Unable to get past a java exception on host = null

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to determine if a url is good or bad. I am unable to get past the exception from HttpURLConnection that host is null.

My code is below:

```
URL url;
UrlValidator validate = new UrlValidator();
if(validate.isValid(rs.getString("url"))){
    url = new URL(rs.getString("url"));
    System.out.println(url.getHost().length());
    if(url.getHost().length() == 0){//testing purposes
        System.out.println("BAD"); //testing purposes
        System.exit(0);//testing purposes
    }
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
    if(connection != null){
        int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(rc);
        /*
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        connection.connect();
        String contentType = connection.getContentType();
        //if(contentType.contains("audio") || contentType.contains("mp3") || contentType.contains("mpeg")){
            System.out.println(contentType+" == "+rs.getString("url"));
        //}
    }
```

I continue to get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2696)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:477)
```

I don't mind the exception but I want to be able to ignore it and I can't.

This is the exact code I am using that is causing the error.

```
                    url = new URL("http://www.hulkshare.com/dl/epsbxff31peb/waka_flocka_flame_ft_drake-round_of_applause_%28remix%29.mp3");
                if(url.getHost() != null){
                    System.out.println("Good Url");
                    //System.exit(0);

                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
                    if(connection != null){
                    int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println(rc);

                    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                    connection.connect();
                    String contentType = connection.getContentType();
                        System.out.println(contentType);

                    }
                }
```

maybe someone can test it on their eclipse and see if they can replicate the error or it's just me.

**UPDATE**

here is the method I made to try to return false on the above exception.

```
    public static boolean isValidURL(){
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.hulkshare.com/dl/epsbxff31peb/waka_flocka_flame_ft_drake-round_of_applause_%28remix%29.mp3");

        //System.out.println(url.getHost());
        if(url.getHost().length() == 0 || url.getHost() == null){
            System.out.println("BAD");
            //System.exit(0);
            return false;
        }else{
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
            if(connection != null){
            int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(rc);

            connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            connection.connect();
            String contentType = connection.getContentType();
            //if(contentType.contains("audio") || contentType.contains("mp3") || contentType.contains("mpeg")){
                System.out.println(contentType);
            //}
            }
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method continues to throw the exception. I am stuck here and can't get past this exception.

Comment: Host can't be null. That doesn't make any sense for a URL.

Comment: What do you mean by " I dont mind the exception " LOL

Comment: You can't ignore exceptions. You'll have to `catch` it at least, or improve your code so it won't happen.

Comment: I understand host can't be null, yet it comes back null for an active URL. I don't mind the exception meaning I can ignore that URL if it throws an exception. I can't catch the exception even though I have tried. It's coming from HttpURLconnection.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `if (url.getHost() != null)` before trying to open the connection?

Comment: I agree with @VGR - that makes the most sense in this scenario.

Comment: I am trying that. it throws exception not matter what I try.

Comment: Something is very screwy here.  At minimum, your stack trace has been truncated / mangled.

Comment: He already tests whether `url.getHost().length() == 0`.  He doesn't need to test separately whether `url.getHost()` is `null` (because the existing test would throw an NPE in that case).

Comment: I suspect that host is issuing an invalid redirect with no hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your URL. If I run your code with `http://www.example.com/` instead of the hulkshare url, it gets past that line you're stuck on. (It eventually fails for a different reason a few lines lower where you try to set the method to `HEAD` after you've already received the HTTP response code, which you can't do.)

If I try to fetch that file on the command line, it fails too:

```
$ wget "http://www.hulkshare.com/dl/epsbxff31peb/waka_flocka_flame_ft_drake-round_of_applause_%28remix%29.mp3"
--2015-01-21 11:05:11--  http://www.hulkshare.com/dl/epsbxff31peb/waka_flocka_flame_ft_drake-round_of_applause_%28remix%29.mp3
Resolving www.hulkshare.com... 109.201.151.6, 109.201.151.5, 109.201.151.3, ...
Connecting to www.hulkshare.com|109.201.151.6|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: //?force=1 [following]
http://?force=1: Invalid host name.
```

### Update:

I understand now by your comments and question edits, that all you really want to do here is catch an `Exception` and return false. I suspect you're simply not catching the `RuntimeException` that's being thrown. Simply cast a wider net in your `catch` clause:

```
} catch (RuntimeException | IOException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I'm having with that one URL. I don't care that it doesn't work. I care that my application breaks when it reaches that URL. I want to be able to skip it some how.

Comment: Then catch the exception and move on.

Comment: I am trying. I can't. How could I catch the exception in the code i provided.

Comment: @Andy Err, `catch (IllegalArgumentException ...)`? Is it such a mystery?

Comment: I've tried that. It still exits application and throws exception. I am trying to force it to return false instead of the exception but it isn't doing it.

Comment: @Andy Then you didn't do it right. Maybe the `IllegalArgumentException` is wrapped in a `RuntimeException`, as the stack trace may suggest.

Comment: omg. it was right there the whole time. I didn't think it being wrapped. Thank you! It works now. +1 and for the answer that lead here.